# Prove that $4n+2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ for some odd $x,y$ and even $z$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Show that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, exists $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $x,y$ are odd and $z$ is even, such that $4n+2=x^2+y^2+z^2$.

I started by using the fact that every natural number has a decomposition to a sum of 4 square, and tried to prove that one of the numbers is zero, basically $4n+2=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$.

Firstly, I falsely assumed that all of those numbers weren't 0, and then I proved that at least one of those numbers has to be odd, because if they were all even then $4n+2=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2 \equiv 0 (mod 4)$, contradicting the fact that $4n+2\equiv 2 (mod 4)$. Then I showed that since $4n+2$ is even then there have to be 2 even numbers exactly and 2 odd numbers exactly among $x,y,z,w$.

From here I assumed that $x,y$ are odd, and that $z,w$ are even and tried to prove that at least one of $z,w$ is 0, but I didn't really have ideas in this direction, so this didn't work out.

Comment: [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) is a stronger statement. Yours is already  a consequence of [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)

Comment: @miracle173, how is it a consequence of Fermat's two-squares theorem?

Comment: @BarryCipra Sorry, that is a mistake

Comment: there is a complete proof in L. E. Dickson, Modern Elementary Theory of Numbers (1939). The first step is to show that for a symmetric matrix $F,$ which is 3 by 3, positive definite, and all entries are integers,  AND $\det F = 1,$ there is another integer matrix $P$ such that $P^T F P = I, $ where $\det P = \pm 1$ by construction. Which means that, if you can place your target number $4n+2$ as the entry $F_{11}$ of such a matrix, and write $Q = P^{-1},$ the expression $Q^T  Q = F $ shows how to write $F_{11}$ as the sum of three integer squares. I don't see any shortcuts for your problem.

Comment: In case of curiosity: I put several items about positive ternary quadratic forms at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x and y are odd while z is even, then you can set $x = 2a+1, y = 2b+1, z = 2c$

$4n+2 = (2a+1)^2+(2b+1)^2+(2c)^2 = 4a^2 + 4a+1+4b^2+4b+1+4c^2 = 4(a^2+a+b^2+b+c^2)+2$

Now you're trying to prove that every possible $n$ can be described as $n = a^2+a+b^2+b+c^2 = a(a+1) + b(b+1) + c^2$

Note that $a(a+1)+b(b+1) \equiv 0 (mod 2)$

Does this help?

Comment: it is already $$a(a+1) \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$ and  $$b(b+1) \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$